# What is the vocabulary in the Homeric dialect for the parts of the body?

Tags: vocabulary, ancient-greek, homer

What is the vocabulary in the Homeric dialect for the parts of the body? Collecting these is a somewhat time-consuming process, because often the Greek concepts don't map one-to-one onto the English ones. Therefore it's not as easy as just making a list in English and finding all the translations.

Answer (score 3):

I mainly collected these simply by paging through Cunliffe. I also tried to think of body parts as conceptualized by English speakers, and I consulted a thesis by Camagni, Manchester, 2017, https://www.research.manchester.ac.uk/portal/files/86865466/FULL_TEXT.PDF . The frequency counts are total occurrences in the Iliad and Odyssey. For inflected forms that don't actually occur in Homer, I've done my best to guess. A spelling like ἰγνύ_η means that the upsilon is long. I've made a couple of recordings involving the relevant grammar and vocabulary: [part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=flGOgB7cNwI), [part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vD0qPwbHdo).

The list includes some animal body parts such as hooves and wings, as well as substances like blood, tears, and ichor.  I couldn't find any word for "anus," although there are such terms in Attic. The only word I could find for "finger" occurs in Homer only as part of the set phrase "rosy-fingered dawn." There seems to be no word for "thumb," or for the entire arm or the entire leg.  I haven't included non-material terms like θυμός, although it's not really clear to me whether there was a distinction between mind and body. Several words like φρήν, πραπίδες, σπλάγχνα, στέρνον, and ὦμος refer to a material organ but also to some abstract faculty or emotion supposedly seated in that organ.

| nom | gen | frequency | gender | decl | definition | notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ἀγκών | ἀγκῶνος | 8 | m | 3 | elbow |  |
| ἀγοστός | ἀγοστοῦ | 5 | m | 2 | palm, arm, filth | more commonly παλάμη |
| αἷμα | αἵματος | 116 | n | 3 | blood |  |
| αἰδοῖον | αἰδοίου | 1 | n | 2 | the genitals | in Homer only once as the genitive plural |
| αὐχήν | αὐχένος | 40 | m | 3 | neck |  |
| βραχίων | βραχίονος | 6 | m | 3 | upper arm, shoulder |  |
| γένειον | γενείου | 7 | n | 2 | chin |  |
| γενειάδες | γενειάδων | 1 | f | 3 | cheeks | sing γενειάς nonexistent in Homer, would mean beard; more common παρήιον |
| γένυς | γένυος | 3 | f | 3 | jaw |  |
| γλουτός | γλουτοῦς | 3 | m | 2 | buttock, plural=butt |  |
| γλῶσσα | γλώσσης | 12 | f | 1 | tongue |  |
| γόνυ | γουνός | 122 | n | 3 | knee | gen also γούνατος |
| δάκρυ | δάκρυος | 103 | n | 3 | tear | gen unattested, guessed based on μῶλυος and other forms of δάκρυ, but cf. ἄστυ/ἄστεος; also δάκρυον, δακρύου |
| δάκτυλος |  |  |  |  | finger, toe | only in H in rhododactylos heos; there is no separate word for thumb |
| δειρή | δειρῆς | 13 | f | 1 | neck, throat, mane |  |
| δέρμα | δέρματος | 14 | n | 3 | skin, hide |  |
| ἐγκέφαλος | ἐγκεφάλοιο | 10 | m | 2 | brain |  |
| ἔντερα | ἐντέρου | 6 | n | 2 | entrails | seldom in singular, indexed by perseus under singular ἔντερον |
| ἧπαρ | ἥπατος | 9 | n | 3 | liver |  |
| ἦτορ | ἤτορος | 93 | n | 3 | heart | gen unattested in homer, only sing nom & acc occur |
| θέμεθλα | θεμέθλων | 4 | n | 2 | eye socket, lower part (of the throat) | plural only |
| θέναρ | θέναρος | 1 | n | 3 | palm [more commonly παλάμη; outside of Homer, can also mean flat of foot] |  |
| θρίξ | τριχός | 14 | f | 3 | hair |  |
| ἰγνύ_η | ἰγνύας | 1 | f | 1 | back of the knee, hamstring | indexed by perseus under ἰγνύα |
| ἴουλος | ἰούλου | 1 | m | 2 | whisker | occurs as plural ἰούλους |
| ἰχώρ |  | 2 | m | 3 | blood of a god, various other fluids; accusative ἰχῶ |  |
| καρπός | καρποῦ | 24 | m | 2 | wrist |  |
| κεφαλή | κεφαλῆς | 137 | f | 1 | head |  |
| κνήμη | κνήμης | 16 | f | 1 | calf, lower leg |  |
| κόμη | κόμης | 13 | f | 1 | hair |  |
| κοτύλη | κοτύλης | 5 | f | 1 | hip socket |  |
| κρανίον | κρανίου | 1 | n | 2 | skull |  |
| κρόταφος | κροτάφοιο | 11 | m | 2 | temple | of the head |
| λαπάρη | λαπάρης | 7 | f | 1 | flank [indexed by perseus under λαπάρα] |  |
| λαυκανίη | λαυκανίης | 2 | f | 1 | throat | cf φάρυγξ |
| λόφος | λόφου | 15 | m | 2 | nape of the neck | also a hill |
| μαζός | μαζοῖο | 17 | m | 2 | nipple, female breast, one side of a male chest | indexed by perseus under μαστός |
| μέλος | μέλεος | 24 | m | 2 | limb |  |
| μέτωπον | μετώπου | 12 | n | 2 | forehead |  |
| μήδεα | μηδέων | 23 |  |  | genitals, testicles | indexed by perseus as the singular μῆδος; is this only male? |
| μηρός | μηροῦ | 36 | m | 2 | thigh |  |
| μυελός | μυελοῦ | 4 | m | 2 | marrow |  |
| μυ_ών | μυ_ῶνος | 2 | m | 3 | muscle | unattested gen given by Cunliffe, makes sense compared to αἰών |
| νέκυς | νέκυος | 78 | m | 3 | dead body | cf σῶμα |
| νεῦρον | νεύρου | 3 | n | 2 | tendon |  |
| νῶτον | νώτου | 31 | n | 2 | back |  |
| ὀδούς | ὀδόντος | 19 | m | 3 | tooth |  |
| ὄμμα | ὄμματος | 14 | n | 3 | eye |  |
| ὄσσε |  | 31 | n | 2 | eyes | dual |
| ὀμφαλός | ὀμφαλοῦ | 8 | m | 2 | belly button |  |
| ὄνυξ | ὄνυχος | 5 | m | 3 | claw, nail, hoof, talon | cf. ὁπλή; in Homer only as dative plural ὀνύχεσσι |
| ὁπλή | ὁπλῆς | 2 | f | 1 | hoof | cf. ὄνυξ; in Homer only as genitive plural ὁπλέων |
| οὐρή | οὐρῆς |  | f | 1 | tail |  |
| οὖς | οὔατος | 28 | n | 3 | ear |  |
| ὀστέον | ὀστέου | 46 | n | 2 | bone |  |
| οὐλή | οὐλῆς | 5 | f | 1 | scar |  |
| ὀφρύς | ὀφρύος | 20 | f | 3 | eyebrow |  |
| παλάμη | παλάμης | 22 | f | 1 | palm | cf. θέναρ, ἀγοστός |
| παρήϊον | παρήϊου | 5 | n | 2 | cheek [text has diar, perseus omits it from lemma; Also occurs as παρήιον, without the diaresis. Homer frequently uses the epithet καλλιπάρῃος, fair-cheeked, for women and goddesses. Attic παρειά.] |  |
| πῆχυς | πήχεως | 8 | m | 3 | the forearm, from the wrist to the elbow | acc sing πῆχυν, pl πήχεε |
| πλευρά | πλευρᾶς | 5 | f | 1 | rib | only in plural |
| πλόκαμος | πλοκάμου | 1 | m | 2 | lock of hair | from πλέκω, to braid, knit; also πλοχμός |
| πνεύμων | πνεύμονος | 1 | m | 3 | lung |  |
| πούς |  | 287 |  |  | foot |  |
| πραπίδες | πραπίδων | 11 | f | 3 | diaphragm, midriff, seat of wisdom and cunning | only in plural in Homer, and indexed by perseus under plural |
| πρόσωπον | προσώπου | 10 | n | 2 | face |  |
| πτέρνη | πτέρνης | 1 | f | 1 | heel |  |
| πτερόν | πτεροῦ | 10 | n | 2 | feather, wing |  |
| ῥάχις | ῥάχιος | 1 | f | 3 | spine, lower back |  |
| ῥί_ς | ῥι_νός | 15 | f | 3 | nose, nostrils | the plural can mean the nose, i.e., it's thought of as an organ in two halves |
| σπλάγχνα | σπλάγχνων | 9 | n | 2 | guts, seat of feelings | only in plural; famous biblical issue |
| στέρνον | στέρνοιο | 19 | n | 2 | breast, chest, seat of feelings | for men much more commonly στῆθος |
| στῆθος | στήθεος | 191 | n | 3 | breast, chest, seat of feelings |  |
| στόμαχος | στομάχοιο | 3 | m | 2 | throat |  |
| σφονδύλιος |  | 1 |  |  | one of the vertebrae of the neck |  |
| σφυρόν | σφυροῦ | 5 | n | 2 | ankle, foothill |  |
| ὑπήνη | ὑπήνης |  | f | 1 | facial hair | only in ὑπηνήτης, bearded |
| χεῖλος | χείλευς | 10 | n | 3 | lip | only in plural, χείλεσιν, χείλεα |
| χολάδες | χολάδος | 2 | f | 3 | bowels | only in plural; dictionary form is singular χολάς |
| χροιή |  | 1 |  |  | flesh, body, person | rare variant of χρώς |
| χρώς | χροός | 101 | f | 3 | flesh, body, person, visible surface of the flesh (χρόα λευκὸν, μελαίνετο χρόα, etc.) | rarely χροιή |
| στόμα | στόματος | 28 | n | 3 | mouth |  |
| σῶμα | σώματος | 8 | n | 3 | dead body | more commonly νέκυς |
| φάρυγξ | φάρυγος | 2 | n | 3 | throat | cf λαυκανίη |
| φρήν | φρενός | 308 | f | 3 | chest, mind |  |
| χείρ | χειρός | 633 | f | 3 | hand |  |
| ὠλένη | ὠλένης |  | f | 1 | elbow, lower arm | seems to occur only in the epithet λευκώλενος |
| ὦμος | ὤμου | 161 | m | 2 | shoulder | thought of as the seat of strength; cog humerus |

Comment: There's also αἰδοῖα "genitals" (of both sexes).

Comment: @TKR: Nice catch, thanks. According to Cunliffe, this occurs exactly once in Homer, in Iliad 13.568. "Meriones, however, following him departing, smote him with his spear
between the private parts and the navel, where a wound is
particularly painful to miserable mortals." (Buckley) Ow!